# Accessing contents of a file while trying to read uploaded file

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, ssjs

I am trying to load and read a CSV file, but I want to iterate through the lines of a file in APEX rather that JS. The reason is that we expect the CSV files to be large and want to handle that job on the server side.

I am struggling to read the file and pass it's content to the APEX class, it comes back as null.

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="GOS_BulkCSVHandler">

    <aura:attribute name="jsonFileText"  type="String"  /> 
    <aura:attribute name="fileName" type="String" default="No File Selected.." />
    <aura:attribute name="bulkList" type="List"/>
    <lightning:input aura:id="fileupload" accept= '.csv' 
                                            onchange="{!c.handleFilesChange}" 
                                            type="file" 
                                            name="file" 
                                            label="Upload Attachment" 
                                            multiple="false"/>

    <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error">A {!v.fileName} </div>
        FILE TEXT: {!v.jsonFileText} 
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
handleFilesChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var fileName = 'No File Selected..';
        var fileOutput = {};
        var contents = '';
        if (event.getSource().get("v.files").length > 0) {
            var action = component.get('c.getString');
            var file = event.getSource().get("v.files")[0];
            fileName = file['name'];
            //fileResult ;
            //console.log(fileResult);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var dataURL = reader.result;
                console.log(dataURL);

            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
            var test = reader;
            console.log(test);
            action.setParams({
                contents : test
            });

            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                    component.set("v.fileName", fileName);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('NO');
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);

        }
    }
```

Class:

```
public with sharing class GOS_BulkCSVHandler {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getString(String contents) {
        String x = 'test.csv';
        System.debug(contents);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Looks like I am getting issues here:

```
reader.readAsText(file);
var test = reader;
console.log(test);
```

my console output returns NULL and this my class is not getting a string. Can someone please help me to understand why I am not getting contents of my csv file.

Comment: Why do large file sizes lead you to conclude you should send the content to the server and process it there?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I do not know to be entirely honest. This is something our Sr Developer suggested. I think the logic is that CSV data will be used to send a web service request and wait for a response. Once response is received a data table will be populated in a different component. The logic I believe is not to have the user sit there and wait for the response to come back and look as a spinning wheel, but rather do it asynchronously in the back and later be updated on the component.

Comment: You're still going to have the spinning wheel until the async operation completes, no? I would suggest not trying to incorporate another server round trip just to process the file. Keep it on the front end.